# How to highlight a part of an image inside UIImageView?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project that is based on playing audio files for the text in the image displayed. The image has text divided into sentences like the below image (ayah), and the audio files are also divided in the same way. So when the text shows 5 sentences, 5 audio files will be played one after the other.

I need to highlight the text that matches the audio file just like below. Noting that the font is special and can't be changed for the purpose of the app.

I can't use OCR as the text is not in English.

EDIT: Below screenshot is captured from a real app with open source code on this url (https://github.com/quran/quran-ios). But I couldn't figure out how he did it...

Any support is appreciated.

[image: ayah]

Comment: It's definitely not something you want to use `UIImageView` for. If your input is text then use `UITextView` for which you could set `attributedText` with your desired formatting.

Comment: Due to font limitation, the text is available in image format :(

Comment: What kind of limitation? Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: The text is quran "muslim reglion holy book" and it should be presented as is. No fonts can write it as in the image above. This is at least as far as I know.

Comment: If you draw on top of this image, your text will also get affected. If the image doesn't have a background color  and is infact transparent, then you can place the highlight view behind the image.

Comment: @SShahid The image is transparent so the problem of the text being affected or not is not there. The actual problem is how to adjust the colored rectangle to highlight the audio played text.

Comment: I have added a link to the source code of the app where I took the screenshot above. https://github.com/quran/quran-ios. May be someone can understand how he did it.

Comment: you can find the font they use on the Holy Quran 
on this official website 
http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa
I don't very sure if it can be accessible 
If not tell me and I will download all fonts and upload it to you

Comment: @MohamedElBasyouni Hi, did you found the solution already?, which method did you use to highlight the text? is it using image or textview? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it's will be very easy for you if you use Font instead of image!

I did search for what is the actual font they use 
and I found it , this is the font on Holly Quran with the Word file
named: `UthmanicHafs1Ex1Ver12.doc`
so you can copy and past after installing the font

you can download it [here](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/wp02/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/UthmanicHafs1-Ex1-Ver12-browser.zip)

and if this isn't working you can download it from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xctq4383im0hwj/UthmanicHafs1-Ex1-Ver12-browser.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Hi Basil, thanks and that looks promising. But even with TextView, I will have to go for NSAttributedString and do a comparison with every ayah "sentence". The code will be huge. Do you have another way to deal with along with the TextView approach? please